# Ways to force LaTeX structure?

Tags: packages

Some types of publications like for instance module documentation have a clear structure (for instance first one has an introduction section, at the end source code is provided,...)

I was wondering if it LaTeX or some package can force a user to obey a given structure. If the user fails to write a document according to the specified structure, at least an warning should be printed.

Comment: Put the information into a database and then generate LaTeX from that. Otherwise, not in any way that feels natural, IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know you can’t enforce the structure, in a way that `\section` only appear in a distinct order. But you can extend (imitate) the `\maketitle` mechanism.

Define some macros like

```
\newcommand{\mc@introduction}{}
\newcommand{\introduction}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mc@introduction}{#1}%
}
```

(The `mc@` prefix can be chosen freely. I used `mc` for MyClass …)
And use them inside a macro like `\makedocument`

```
\newcommand{\makedocument}{%
    Some text 

    \addsec{Introduction}
    \mc@introduction

    \let\makedocument\relax
}
```

The last line ensures that `\makedocument` can’t be used twice.
And with `etoolbox` you can call `\makedocument` automatically at the end of the document.

```
\AtEndDocument{\makedocument}
```

If some of the information must be provided you may initialize the `\mc@introduction` macro like this

```
\newcommand{\mc@introduction}{
    \ClassError{myclass}{\string\introduction\space not used.}{%
        You must provide the introduction.
    }
}
```

When you redefine the `\section` you can permit to use it in the document

```
\renewcommand{\section}[1][]{%
    \ClassError{myclass}{Don't use \string\section}{%
        You are not allowed to use \string\section
        in your document!
    }
}
```

but you must save the definition *before* redefining if you want to use it in `\makedocument` with

```
\let\addsec\section
```

---

This is a full but very rudimentary example:

```
% myclass-test.tex
\documentclass{myclass}

\begin{document}
\faqs{The order in the document won't change anything.}

\introduction{Text}

%\section{Test}% caues an error

%\makedocument% optional
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

```
% myclass.cls
\ProvidesClass{myclass}

\LoadClassWithOptions{article}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\mc@introduction}{
    \ClassError{myclass}{\string\introduction\space not used.}{%
        You must provide the introduction.
    }
}
\newcommand{\introduction}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mc@introduction}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\mc@information}{}
\newcommand{\information}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mc@information}{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\mc@faqs}{}
\newcommand{\faqs}[1]{%
    \renewcommand{\mc@faqs}{#1}%
}

\let\addsec\section

\renewcommand{\section}[1][2]{%
    \ClassError{myclass}{Don't use \string\section}{%
        You are not allowed to use \string\section
        in your document!
    }
}

\newcommand{\makedocument}{%
    Some text that is always the same in
    every single document.

    \addsec{Introduction}
    \mc@introduction

    \addsec{Information}
    \mc@information

    \addsec{FAQs}
    \mc@faqs

    \let\makedocument\relax
}

\AtEndDocument{\makedocument}
```